# Comparing two dependent Spearman's rank correlation coefficients

Tags: spearman-rho

I would like to test whether there is a significant difference between two dependent Spearman's rank correlation coefficients. I found Steiger's Z test is one of the helpful ways of comparing two dependent correlation coefficients. I would ask whether Steiger's Z test could be used not only for Pearson's correlation coefficients, but also for Spearman's rank correlation coefficients. If it couldn't be used, please teach me any other way of comparing them.

Comment: Maybe this paper is helpful: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/0471667196.ess5050.pub2/abstract